# Hitting a character physics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, collision

Ok, for this task I need to coordinate physics hitting a game object at a certain point and animation, to create the illusion of punching a character and he stumbles back **as if propelled by that contact point.**

I have rigid bodies on both the hitting object and character being hit, and can tell when the hitting object enters the character's box collider. What I thought to do first was create an impulse at the contact point then trigger my pre made character animation -

```
Vector3 direction = (this.transform.position - collider.transform.position) / (this.transform.position - collider.transform.position).magnitude;
        this.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(direction, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Problem is this just makes the character float slowly off opposite the hitting object (Rigidbody has gravity checked on character), and depending on where the character is facing, the animation looks not coordinated with the punch.

I wanted to see whether there's a streamlined way of doing this - how can I create a realistic punch/moving backward situation in Unity?

Comment: If your object is a character, the best way to do this is to apply an animation. There isn't anything built into Unity that creates those type of "stumble" animations, but there are a lot of canned animations available on the Unity Store.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes Ive done the stumble animation, problem is how to determine which direction to stumble. The character can be facing any direction away from the hitter, so if I just trigger the stumble he will likely not stumble AWAY from the hit

Comment: Unity3D should be able to do all of this for you without writing any code

Comment: @MickyD Thats a very vague response. Explain?

Comment: Unity3D has physics; rigid bodies; collisions out of the box. All of this without requiring any code. The problem is not so much coding but having suitable assets and using the Unity3D scene editor

Comment: @MickyD as I said, I've done this. I need to coordinate my ANIMATION with physics

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to get this behavior out-of-the-box with Unity. You will need to script a blending of ragdoll physics with animations.

One approach you might want to try is a system that "pins" your ragdoll to the bones of an animation, and if a collision occurs, the ragdoll unpins itself (partially or completely) from the bones, temporarily.  When/if it completes being affected by physics, you would probably want to animate from a keyframe dynamically created based on the position of the ragdoll to a target keyframe.

There are also tools like [PuppetMaster](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/puppetmaster-48977) on the asset store that are meant to do things like this, but they are often not free, because they are difficult to make well.